# How do we Place order from storefront on behalf of another customer in Magento 2.3?

Tags: checkout, customer, addtocart, tierprice, place-order

The salesperson (sales rep) talk to customers take an order at offline mode, will **Place orders on behalf of them on Storefront**,
So Salesperson logged in to My Magento account (Storefront), he can choose the associated Customer in the customer's contact list and he can add items for that customer and check out, the customer gets an order notification email.

Product price will be displayed according to the associated Customer's Group **(Tier price)**. also, Salesperson can add products to cart with or without negotiated price based on product Min – Max Selling price.

So instead of associated customers can order from the website, Salesperson using his account and do it for them.

Comment: Extension like this should get you most of the way https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-login-as-customer/

Comment: Login As Customer Extension provides login with any customer, for that we required Admin Panel, But I don't want to create multiple admin users with their ACL. I want to access another customer which already assigned with the salesperson, He can login on the frontend (Store) & choose associated customers and place orders for that customer.

Comment: You are going to have to reach out to a developer to get something bespoke created

Comment: @shownakshah have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @Knight017 Magento 2 extension sales rep, which full fill my requirements. https://www.mageb2b.de/en/magento2-extension-salesstaff#funktionsumfang

Answer (score 0):

You can use some free [Login As Customer](https://www.google.com/search?q=login%20as%20customer%20magento%202&oq=login%20as%20customer%20&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2j69i60l2.2759j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) extension for Magento 2, then you can login with any customer on the frontend and place an order on behalf of that customer.

Of course, you can also create an extension for this but this is a quick win for you

Comment: Login As Customer Extension provides login with any customer, for that we required Admin Panel, But I don't want to create multiple admin users with their ACL.  I want all this activity will be done from Frontend (store).